# Getting rid of NA values in R when importing a CSV file

Tags: r, import, na

I am new to R, so bear with me. I want to import a csv file into r that contains blank cells. I want to get rid of NA values. So far I have the following code:

```
    dataActiveShare <- read.csv("ActiveShare.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".", na.strings="NA")
```

However, the data still contain NA values when reading in r. I receive the following error:

```
    Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :   unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

Any ideas how I can ignore the blank cells? (By the way I am not trying to omit rows that contain blank cells)

Comment: What do you want to do with the blank cells?

Comment: I want to ignore them so that I for example can take the mean of a column that contain blank cells.

Comment: This is already what NA does. See na.rm argument for most functions (including mean). A dataframe must have equally-sized rows and columns so NA just exists to mark those blank cells.

Comment: Okay, but my dataframe does not have equally-sized rows and columns, how can I approach this, so that I can ignore NA values?

Comment: You should try to cut down your csv file to a few lines that reproduce the problem and copy those lines in your post. We cannot help you without knowing what's there

Comment: In a dataframe the idea is that each row contains related pieces of data (e.g. from the same sample), with the type of data described by the column. If there is missing data then a NA is the appropriate value to put in that cell. If your data does match the above description then please describe it and we can try to suggest a more appropriate data structure.